# The Adobe process doesn't close after the code is finished

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, bookmarks

I'm adding bookmarks after I merged pdf files. The script does the job, but because of one variant, the Adobe-process doesn’t close after.
The Variants name is "BMA". If removed, then the process will close as designed.
I made a script closing all process, but I want a more solid solution. Please help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testrun()
Dim aInfo(6) As String
'True = bookmark
'False = child bookmark
aInfo(0) = "True,Index,0"
aInfo(1) = "True,Document_1,1"
aInfo(2) = "False,Attatchment_1,2"
aInfo(3) = "True,Document_2,3"
aInfo(4) = "False,Attatchment_1,4"
aInfo(5) = "False,Attatchment_2,5"
Call NewFixPDF("C:\Temp\Test.pdf", aInfo)
End Sub

Private Sub NewFixPDF(sFile As String, aInfo() As String)

Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
Dim PDDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

Dim jso As Object
Dim BMR As Object, oBMR As Object, oBMA As Object
Dim BMA As Variant

Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set PDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, i As Integer
Dim aBookmark() As String

Dim bHead As Boolean
Dim sName As String
Dim iPage As Integer

If PDDoc.Open(sFile) = False Then
    MsgBox "Can't open file", vbCritical
    GoTo Exit_Sub
End If

Set jso = PDDoc.GetJSObject
jso.bookmarkRoot.Remove
Set BMR = jso.bookmarkRoot
Set oBMR = jso.bookmarkRoot

For i = 0 To UBound(aInfo) - 1

    aBookmark = Split(aInfo(i), ",")
    bHead = aBookmark(0)
    sName = aBookmark(1)
    iPage = aBookmark(2)
    
    If bHead Then
        If InStr(sName, "-") > 0 Then sName = Mid(sName, 3 + Len(sName) - InStr(StrReverse(sName), "-"))
        BMR.createchild sName, "this.pageNum = " & iPage, a
        BMA = BMR.Children
        Set oBMA = BMA(a)
        a = a + 1
        b = 0
    Else
        oBMA.createchild sName, "this.pageNum = " & iPage, b
        b = b + 1
    End If
Next i

If PDDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, sFile) = False Then
    MsgBox "Can't add bookmarks", vbCritical
End If

Exit_Sub:
Set BMR = Nothing
Set oBMR = Nothing
Set oBMA = Nothing

PDDoc.Close
AcroApp.Exit
Set AcroApp = Nothing
Set PDDoc = Nothing

Debug.Print "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is BMA an array of Adobe objects?  Perhaps try cleaning it up in your Exit Sub logic?

Comment: I tryed "BMA = Empty" but it doesn't help and yes, it's some kind of an array.

Comment: You could try getting rid of BMA and change the following line like this: `Set oBMA = BMR.Children(a)`.

Comment: I get error 13
incompatible types
When I try
`Set oBMA = BMR.Children(a)`